# How can we control the device driver load order in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, windows-registry, scanner, ordering

We are trying to install both an HP scanner and a Kodak scanner on an XP machine and the problem is that HP's scanner driver always places itself into the first and default scanner device position. We are using an automation software on that machine which must use the Kodak scanner as the default scanner. The HP flatbed isn't needed to be the default scanner on that machine and it will always be used manually through its own software. Our developers did some research 2 years ago and couldn't find a solution. Nowadays we are preparing to expand our user base and this problem did surface again on off-site user machines with the same configuration.

I did a more aggresive search on the net and found some tips like this one : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115486

I couldn't realize how to suit this solution to my scenario. Could someone please point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Uhm 2 years? Kinda can't figure this out. You use an automatic solution , rite. But you apply 2 kind of scanners at EVERY install? IF thats the case then dont care about this >> What about disabling the device and providing a button OR enable it when the users logs in?

Comment: The problem is that we have average users and they don't want to play with power buttons or do some other stuff to be able to do their jobs on the machines. At the end the software and the OS are supposed to work that way.

Comment: Try a bounty if you really need help, you're asking a too localized problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows XP, if I set a scanner as default, it's always the default when that scanner is on...

Developers and instructions can't help you out, your best bet is to upgrade or work around the problem.